# Syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression Was working before?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class cards
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     one();
  }

  public static void one()
  {
    int [] deck = new int [52];

    System.out.println(deck[1]);

    for(int [i]= 0; i<deck.length; i++)
    {
      deck[i]=i+1;
      System.out.println(deck[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This code is some piece of an array. I'm using to make a deck of cards that shuffles and it seems to be getting an odd error one that doesn't make any sense to me.

It was working one day, I didn't change anything and now its not working anymore.

Comment: Where you get the error?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 for(int [i]= 0; i<deck.length; i++)
```

to

```
 for(int i= 0; i<deck.length; i++)
```

There is absolutely no possibility that this code worked one day as is.

Comment: Thankyou this helped I have to wait 10 minutes before checking.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(int [i]= 0; i<deck.length; i++)
```

To

```
for(int i= 0; i<deck.length; i++)
```

I don't know why you have placed the square brackets around `i`. What you need to do is to declare the variable `i` and initialize it to 0. The proper way to do that is without the square brackets.